# Statsmodels: Regression by subgroups

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a `pandas` dataframe that contains as fields `x`, `y`, `year`. `year` has values `[-100, 100, 1999]`. I want to create subgroups by year and run `reg x y`.

I am aware that I can solve this on the pandas side through something similar to

```
for y in df.year.unique():
    smf.ols('y ~ x', data=df.loc[df.year == y])
```

I am wondering whether there is a nicer way to do that within statsmodels, something like `smf.ols('y ~ x', data=df, by=['year'])`. The (very light) documentation didn't mention this, but it appears as a core feature to me that really should be supported.

Comment: No, it's not supported. There are a few models like proportional hazard model that support strata. And the formula interface also has a `subset` option, but not a `by` option.

Comment: In a new question, the answer used pandas groupby for a similar task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657226/can-pandas-groupby-transform-a-dataframe-into-a-series/32658503#32658503